# Select one of three columns if not null

Tags: sql, oracle

```
NAME | TELEPHONE_1 | TELEPHONE_2 | TELEPHONE_3
Max  | 00491633888 | NULL        | NULL
Soph | NULL        | NULL        | NULL
Pes  | NULL        | 0049163232  | 0049111111
```

For Max the output should be 00491633888
For Soph the output should be NULL
For Pes the output should be the first found entry. So TELEPHONE 2 -> 0049163232

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN TELEPHONE_1  IS NOT NULL THEN TELEPHONE_1 
    ELSE WHEN TELEPHONE_2 IS NOT NULL THEN TELEPHONE_2  
    ELSE WHEN TELEPHONE_3 IS NOT NULL THEN TELEPHONE_3 
    ELSE NULL END AS TELEPHONE
FROM test
```

This is my try, but it is not working.

Comment: The case expression syntax has one ELSE only (and it's optional.) I.e. `case when ... then ... when ... then ... [else ...] end`. (And ELSE NULL is not needed, the NULL value will automatically be returned if no WHEN has been true.)

Answer (score 4):

Use `coalesce`; it'll return the 1st non-null value:

```
select name,
  COALESCE(telephone_1, telephone_2, telephone_3) as telephone
from test
```

---

Demo:

```
SQL> with test (name, telephone_1, telephone_2, telephone_3) as
  2    (select 'Max' , '00491633888', null        , null         from dual union all
  3     select 'Soph', null         , null        , null         from dual union all
  4     select 'Pes' , null         , '0049163232', '0049111111' from dual
  5    )
  6  select name,
  7    COALESCE(telephone_1, telephone_2, telephone_3) as telephone
  8  from test;

NAME TELEPHONE
---- -----------
Max  00491633888
Soph
Pes  0049163232

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

(my original post) : "The NVL() function takes a list of expressions and returns the first non-null value"

I was wrong, NVL() only takes 2 arguments. COALESCE() is more standard and more flexible.

Comment: That is not true, dami.

Comment: `nvl` functions takes only two arguments (and is DBMS specific)

Comment: I.e. always use `COALESCE()`!

Comment: you are right, my mistake. I'll remove the answer

Answer (score 0):

You do not want the `ELSE` keyword before the `WHEN` (remove those and then your code works):

```sql
SELECT name,
       CASE
       WHEN TELEPHONE_1 IS NOT NULL THEN TELEPHONE_1 
       WHEN TELEPHONE_2 IS NOT NULL THEN TELEPHONE_2  
       WHEN TELEPHONE_3 IS NOT NULL THEN TELEPHONE_3 
       ELSE NULL
       END AS TELEPHONE
FROM   test
```

Outputs:

| NAME | TELEPHONE |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 00491633888 |
| Soph | *null* |
| Pes | 0049163232 |

---

You could also use `COALESCE` (which is part of the ANSI standard):

```sql
SELECT name,
       COALESCE(TELEPHONE_1, TELEPHONE_2, TELEPHONE_3) AS TELEPHONE
FROM   test
```

or `NVL` (which is an Oracle function and only takes 2 arguments):

```sql
SELECT name,
       NVL(TELEPHONE_1, NVL(TELEPHONE_2, TELEPHONE_3)) AS TELEPHONE
FROM   test
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2CzbOaol)